# Accessing Nested Elements

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to build a dataframe from a JSON string returned from an API call.

My schema looks like:

> root
> |-- report: struct (nullable = true)
> |  |-- payments: array (nullable = true)
> |  |  |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
> |  |  |  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
> |  |  |  |-- count: string (nullable = true)
> |  |  |  |-- flowName: string (nullable = true)
> |  |  |  |-- date: string (nullable = true)
> |  |  |  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
> |  |  |  |-- amount: string (nullable = true)

My end goal is to produce a data frame with the column headers being the id, count, flowName, date, name, and amount. I have had no luck with utilizing the explode function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply you `explode` for array type,

```
  df.select(explode($"report.payments") as "col")
    .select("col.*").show(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inline`:

```
val df2 = df.selectExpr("inline(report.payments)")
```